# *Help* Learn Python Tutorial Modules and Packages

Tags: python

I'm stuck in an exercise on learnpython.org referring to Modules and Packages.

The Exercise is: In this exercise, you will need to print an alphabetically sorted list of all functions in the re module, which contain the word find.

The Code I put:

```
 import re
for x in dir(re):
    if x[:4] == "find":
        print x
```

Code Output:

```
findall
finditer
```

Expected Output:

```
['findall', 'finditer']
```

What I tried after:

```
import re
for x in dir(re):
    if x[:4] == "find":
        print list(x)
```

What I got:

```
['f', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'l', 'l']
['f', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'i', 't', 'e', 'r']
```

Please help me I can figure out what to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to print that list:

```
import re
print [x for x in dir(re) if x[:4] == "find"]
```

You are currently calling `list(x)` where `x` is a string. That means it'll convert the string into a list of characters and that's why you're seeing output such as `['f', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'l', 'l']`.

If you have not yet read about list comprehensions you can do:

```
import re
result = []
for x in dir(re):
    if x[:4] == "find":
        result.append(x) 
print result
```

which will build the same list as well. You can also use `startswith()`:

```
import re
result = []
for x in dir(re):
    if x.startswith("find"):
        result.append(x) 
print result
```

Comment: It is because `dir()` returns results in alphabetical order: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking that also to. Just a question. Im very new to python but why did you do x for x in dir(re). Instead of like for x in dir(re)

Comment: @user2395335: In a list comprehension you need to specify what element you wish to add to the list and, in this case, those elements come from `dir(re)`. So we want each element `x` for each `x` that is in `dir(re)`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the result is a string, by using `list(x)` you converting it into a list of characters - instead just print `x` to get the string. What you want to be doing though is appending to a list and then sorting it...

```
import re
names = []
for name in dir(re):
    if name[:4] == 'find':
        names.append(name)

names.sort()
print names
```

Which can be written as a generator and ordered by using `sorted`:

```
print sorted(name for name in dir(re) if name.startswith('find'))
```

**Note - as [Simeon Visser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267329/simeon-visser) has kindly pointed out - `dir` already pre-sorts its results, so the sort steps aren't actually necessary!**

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled by this one too for awhile.  My thought train started by looking at the RE (Regular Expressions) module itself which contained a string regular expression search function which I used as below which worked fine...

```
import re
mylist=[]
for x in dir(re):
    match = re.search('find', x)
    if match:
            mylist.append(x)
print mylist
```